# AngularJs alternative to ng-if to save digest

Tags: angularjs, performance, digest

I recently started studying about digest and performance improvements in AngulaJs and found on my website that I'm using tons of `ng-if`.

Sometimes in `ng-if` there is a variable that may change, but often is fixed at the startup of the controller and then never changes.

What should I do so to improve performance avoiding digest to evaluate every loop those unchangeable `ng-if`? Should I change directive? With what?

E.g

In my header template I have a div that can be seen only by particular type of user. It's just a div, so I don't want to call some different template.
I put `<div ng-if="userIsSuperior()"> ... </div>`

When first evaluated, the return vale of `userIsSuperior()` never changes (during this session of course), but I know that AngularJs Digest evaluates it every loop.
How can I avoid this? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hard to answer without some specific examples

Comment: Added an example. I got really lot of them, most with functions in controller that returns true or false based on some calculations (that may become really expensive if website raise) and some with just a variable.

Comment: Well one thing is it's always better to set scope model properties than use functions in view like `userIsSuperior()`. Saves  lot of needless function calls during digests

Comment: I would say the area you need to be more concerned about is within `ng-repeat`. Having numerous `ng-if` inside loop will stack up a lot more watchers than worrying about individual standalone elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [one-time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding).

If you use:

```
<div ng-if="::userIsSuperior()"> ... </div>
```

Then the value of `userIsSuperior()` will only be calculated once and will stick to that value.

See [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/nKQgeQ3TDUGE1qshY1p1?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

First answer solutions needs AngularJS > 2.

I found a valid solutions in using OnceJS, library for one-time-binding.

[Here](https://github.com/tadeuszwojcik/angular-once)